# Connecting to the Internet on a PI 1

Tags: wifi, pi-1

To start, I have been looking through alot of similar questions, but they all seemed to have the same solution that didnt work for me. I am working on a PI 1 Model B. This doesn't have Wifi onboard, so I have a 802.11n usb wifi connecter. I have used this PI before and have been able to connect to the internet, and while not impossible, i would highly doubt the board has been damaged since then.

I recently installed a fresh instance of the Raspbian from the imager, and have it set up a "connected to the wifi". I am able to ssh into the machine, and it shows wifi bars above, but I cannot use the terminal for any internet facing tasks, such as pinging a location off my network. Strangely I am to connect to use the browser to connect to the internet, though verrrrry slowly; sugesting the problem lies with the terminal set-up somehow.

Some of the solutions I have tried include:

1) Adding the one of following to my /etc/network/interfaces file

```
#Attempt 1
auto lo

inface lo inet loopback
inface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_suppliciant.conf
iface default inet dhcp



#Attempt 2
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.212 
netmask 255.255.255.0 
network 192.168.1.0 
broadcast 192.168.1.255 
gateway 192.168.1.1

#Both attempts disabled my connection not allowing me to ssh in until i removed them.
```

I also have this in my /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf file

```
network={
        ssid=NAME_OF_NETWORK
        psk=PASSWORD_OF_NETWORK
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        pairwise=CCMP
        auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

where both name and password are correct.

2) Using a ethernet cable, didnt seem to change any of this, beyond the ip address being used.

3) A number of small changes to the above attempts, none of which were meaningfully different from what I could see, and none worked better, and weren't trying to solve my route problem.

The output of route -n is (note the Ip address was 192.168.1 113 for wifi and 101 for ethernet, not sure if they are meant to appear in the routing table or not.)

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

So, that leaves the underlying problem. Why can my terminal not ping www.google.com / install any packages, but it can browse the web?

EDIT: The wifi dongle being used works on a windows machine, and worked on the PI when i used it before a couple of years ago on a different install

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address)

Comment: Nope, I tried both of the top answers there, but neither worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be quickest to start from a fresh image.

In file

```
/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

have the following entry, changing GB to your country code.

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=GB

network={
    ssid="your ssid"
    psk="your password"
}
```

Undo every other change you have made to network settings.

Comment: This is what it was set up as initially, but does not work, just tried it, including a reboot

Comment: Perhaps you have a faulty or unsupported wireless dongle.  I suggest you edit your question staring from this base and add any diagnostics you can think of.

Comment: It also doesnt seem to work with ethernet, so Im not sure its a problem there. Ill try see if i can test out it on a seperate system first.

Comment: Wifi dongle works fine on a windows PC, and has worked fine in the past with the PI (last used maybe a couple of years ago with a differnent install